# Get xpath to tag which contains certain text

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the xpath to some text on a webpage.  If you were to go to https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html and try and get the xpath of "EXERCISE" it would look like "html body html table tbody tr td div h4".  If you go to that page, right click on "EXERCISE" and inspect it, you can see the path at the bottom of the code (in chrome).

I have tried numerous paths.  None of which have got the desired result.  This is the closest i got:

```
soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')
tags = [{"name":tag.name,"text":tag.text,"attributes":tag.attributes} for tag in soup.find_all()]
s = ''
for t in tags:
    if "EXERCISE" in t['text']:
        s = s + t['name'] + " "
print(s)
```

At the start i need to get "html body html table tbody tr td div h4", but eventually with more complicated pages, i need to get the tag attributes as well

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using xpath to locate the element. Is that the intention?

Comment: Exactly, i'm using the exact text to locate the element, and want to return the path to it.

Comment: You tagged BeautifulSoup - do you want just xpath? It can be done various ways...with CSS selector also

Comment: I'd be happy using any way really.  I just need to work out the path that I can give back to soup.select() so it can return the text again.  Reason i tagged xpath is because I used it in one of my attempts

Comment: Can you use lxml?

Comment: Yeah i can. Can use any method at all really

Comment: The XPath to select any element with a text node containing `'EXERCISE'` string is `//*[text()[contains(.,'EXERCISE')]]`. This `/html/body/hmtl/table/tr/td/div/h4` is just an XPath expression to select that `h4` element without any other semantic meaning.

Comment: There are other questions and answers in the site to get some absolute path for a selected node, even there is one from the [XPath 2.0 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string-join): `fn:string-join(for $n in ancestor-or-self::* return name($n), '/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lxml:

```
url = 'https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html'

import requests
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
page  = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

root = etree.fromstring(page.content,parser)

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
e = root.xpath('.//*[text()="EXERCISE"]')
print(tree.getpath(e[0]))
```

Output:

> /html/body/hmtl/table/tr/td/div[2]/h4

Comment: This helped a lot.  I ended up using this, splitting the output and then looping through each one doing a soup.select() and grabbing the attributes.  Nice one

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the tag you want is always going to have the exact text of "EXERCISE" (no quotes, or different later cases, white space, etc.), then you can just use a `.find` on the exact text.  Though you could also use a regular expression instead in case you do want to check for white space variations and what not.

From there, you can utilize `.parents` to get a list of the objects ancestors, meaning the element that contains it, the element that contains that element, and so on up to the top of the document.  Then just extract the tag names, reverse the list, and join everything together.

```
thetag = soup.find(string="EXERCISE")
parent_tags = [ p.name for p in list(thetag.parents) ]
print('/'.join(parent_tags[::-1]))
```

Output:

> [document]/html/body/hmtl/table/tr/td/div/h4

If you don't want that "`[document]`" at the start, you could take it out along the way in any number of ways, for example use these lines instead of the last two:

```
parent_tags = [ p.name for p in list(thetag.parents)[:-1] ]
print('/' + '/'.join(parent_tags[::-1]))
```

Output:

> /html/body/hmtl/table/tr/td/div/h4

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense and seems to be very efficient.  The problem is that the output is 
```[document]/hmtl/body/table/tr/td/div/p/p/p/p/h4```

so it has the p's in there. they open and close before the h4, so the h4 isn't actually within them if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Selector `:contains(EXERCISE):not(:has(:contains(EXERCISE)))` will select innermost tag that contains string "EXERCISE".

Then we use method `find_parents()` to find all parents of this tag and print their names:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

t = soup.select_one(':contains(EXERCISE):not(:has(:contains(EXERCISE)))')
# you can use also this:
# t = soup.find(text="EXERCISE").find_parent()    

#lets print the path
tag_names = [t.name, *[t.name for t in t.find_parents()]]
print(' > '.join(tag_names[::-1]))
```

Prints:

```
[document] > hmtl > body > table > tr > td > div > p > p > p > p > h4
```